# how to add imagebutton in listview items?

Tags: android, listview, android-imagebutton

I have a listview that is dynamically loaded with video links from the mysql database. when I click on an element of my listview, I launch the video corresponding to the element but now I would like to add an imagabutton in each element of my listview so that the user can download the corresponding video. I know how to use Download Manager to manage download but how to make my image button clickable without canceling the click of the element of the lisview and how to download the exact video corresponding to each element of the listview?

**Here is my Adapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private String[] androidosnames;
private String[] titre;
private String[] url;
private Bitmap[] bitmaps;
private Activity context;

public CustomAdapter(Activity context, String[] androidosnames, String[] titre, Bitmap[] bitmaps, String[] url) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, androidosnames);
    this.context = context;
    this.url = url;
    this.titre = titre;
    this.bitmaps = bitmaps;
    this.androidosnames = androidosnames;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    final View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);

    TextView androidos = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvandroidosnames);
    TextView textView = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.url);
    TextView titresong = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.titre);

    androidos.setText(androidosnames[position]);
    titresong.setText(titre[position]);
    textView.setText(url[position]);

    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textView.setSelected(true);
    androidos.setSelected(true);

    ImageView image = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imgvw);
    image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps[position], 100, 100, false));

    return listViewItem;
```

**Here is my listview item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgvw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titre"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgvw"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgvw"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvandroidosnames"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgvw"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgvw"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titre"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="url;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/url"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgvw"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgvw"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titre"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="url;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/coeur"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_like"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="85dp"/>
```

**and here is the code that allows me to start the video in another activity**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayVideo.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", GetJson.urla[i]);
            intent.putExtra("name", GetJson.Android_Name[i]);
            intent.putExtra("title", GetJson.titre[i]);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_back_in, R.anim.activity_back_out);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: (The idea here is to add onClickListener() for each of the views of each item inside the list --- when user clicks anything other than imageView, Launch video otherwise download video. This code is not tested. If while testing you encounter a problem just write a comment down below).

1) MnnnnnnnActivity.class:-------------

```
 public class MnnnnnnnActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListItemListener {

private ListView lv;
private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
private String[] androidnames;
private String[] titre;
private Bitmap[] bitmaps;
private String[] url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout6);

    //populate arrays (androidnames, titre , bitmaps , url);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext() , androidnames , titre , bitmaps , url , MnnnnnnnActivity.this);
    lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);

}

@Override
public void Launch_Video(int position) {

}

@Override
public void Download_Video(int position) {

}
}
```

2) CustomAdapter.class:-------

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private String[] androidosnames;
private String[] titre;
private String[] url;
private Bitmap[] bitmaps;
private Context context;
private ListItemListener callback;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] androidosnames, String[] titre, Bitmap[] bitmaps, String[] url , ListItemListener l) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_view_item, androidosnames);
    this.context = context;
    this.url = url;
    this.titre = titre;
    this.bitmaps = bitmaps;
    this.androidosnames = androidosnames;
    if(l != null){
        callback = l;
    }

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.androidos = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvandroidosnames);
        holder.androidos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(callback != null){
                    callback.Launch_Video(position);
                }
            }
        });


        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.url);
        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(callback != null){
                    callback.Launch_Video(position);
                }
            }
        });


        holder.titresong = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titre);
        holder.titresong.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(callback != null){
                    callback.Launch_Video(position);
                }
            }
        });


        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgvw);
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(callback != null){
                    callback.Download_Video(position);
                }
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.androidos.setText(androidosnames[position]);
    holder.titresong.setText(titre[position]);
    holder.textView.setText(url[position]);

    holder.textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.textView.setSelected(true);
    holder.androidos.setSelected(true);

    holder.image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps[position], 100, 100, false));

    return convertView;

}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView androidos;
    TextView textView;
    TextView titresong;
    ImageView image;
}

}
```

3) ListItemListener interface:----------

```
public interface ListItemListener {

public void Launch_Video(int position);

public void Download_Video(int position);
}
```

4) layout6.xml:--------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lv">
</ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

5) list_view_item.xml is the same as list_item.